# Local computer and remote computer are behind NAT. How to make local network accessible with SOCKS?

Tags: ssh, nat, ssh-tunnel, reverse-proxy, socks-proxy

I have a

- Local computer (behind NAT).
- An intermediate server which is publicly    accessible and has a
  fixed IP address.
- Remote computer (behind NAT and not the same as local computer).

**I’d like to temporarily share access to a website on the local network via the local computer and an intermediate server using SOCKS/SSH, so that a remote computer can view it.** Is this possible when both the remote computer and the local computer are **behind NAT**? If yes, how?

```
                      NAT       -   Static Public IP  - NAT
Local Network <- Local Computer - Intermediate Server - Remote Computer
```

I know I can do this with ngrok and similar services, but I would like to learn how to do it myself using SSH and SOCKS.

**Bounty:** I will give preference to answers with example code and explanations on how to do it. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I require SOCKS for dynamic port forwarding.
[image: SOCKS with multiple hops]

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use port forwarding?

Comment: For SSH, just add a tunnel option that points an arbitrary port to the local site and port number (i.e. tunnel port `10000` to `<host>:<server port>`, which can then be accessed via `https://127.0.0.1:10000`)

Comment: @SamForbis I vaguely recall some mention of port forwarding causing problems if you use absolute links? Probably not an issue in my case, but if I have to forward more than just port 443 and port 80 it will become a pain. In that case, it would be better to use socks (or at least that is what I think).

Comment: @JW0914 Sorry could you elaborate a little?

Comment: For example on the local computer I should run, `ssh -DN 10000:intermediate-server-ip:22 -i /home/private.pem`  or something like that?

Comment: @TryHarder You'll utilize `-L local_port:remote_address:remote_port`.  See [How to Use SSH Tunneling to Access Restricted Servers](https://www.howtogeek.com/168145/how-to-use-ssh-tunneling/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want/need dynamic port forwarding you could try the following configuration:

l-user : user on my-local-computer
i-user : user on intermediate
intermediate : ip address of the intermediate host

on my-local-computer:

```
ssh -R 10022:localhost:22 i-user@intermediate
```

on the-remote:

```
ssh -D 3456 -J i-user@intermediate -p 10022 l-user@localhost
```

The remote port forwarding between `my-local-computer` and `intermediate` must exist before the connection from `the-remote` is initiated.

In this configuration `the-remote` acts as an SOCKS5 proxy on port 3456 and forwards the traffic via the `intermediate` to `my-local-comuter` where it should end in your local lan.

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for, thanks! I'm just working through it now.

Comment: At first this didn't work for me. I was using `ssh -vvv -D 3456 -J i-user@intermediate l-user@localhost:10022` to debug. It would make the connect to the intermediate server, but then I would get -"`getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor`" when trying to connect to mylocal.

Comment: To fix the problem on both the-remote and intermediate I created `~/.ssh/config` and added `Host intermediate user i-user HostName intermediate-ip StrictHostKeyChecking no IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa Port 22 Host mylocal user l-user StrictHostKeyChecking no HostName 127.0.0.1 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa Port 10022`

Comment: After I created the `~/.ssh/config` files, I changed the command to `ssh -vvv -D 3456 -J i-user@intermediate l-user@mylocal`

Comment: Another thing, I had to add the local website to `/etc/hosts` on the-remote because the DNS ignored my local router's DNS settings-it was resolving to the wrong website. The other thing is that it won't work if there is no openssh server running on mylocal. I originally thought just using the ssh client would be fine. Lastly I set `AllowTCPforwarding yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: @TryHarder sorry just realized that one mistake didn't get changed in my last edit. The port 10022 can't be attached to the ip address like I wrote in the beginning.  It must be written like `-p 10022`.  I just changed that now again.

Comment: @ TryHarder  The `~/.ssh/config` files are not required, but make things more comfortable. It also should work with the ip addresses. Also, since there will be a connection made from the intermediate to my-local, there is a ssh-server required on my-local to answer this connection. Sorry to not point that out in detail.

Comment: you should explain the switches like -J

Comment: @ TryHarder  I'm a bit irritated about the DNS issue. I was under the impression that resolving the DNS-Name was done by the 'exit' of the proxy and not the workstation. I guess I have to research this again.

Comment: @barlop yupp, that could be done... but in the end that would most likely be like a copy&past form the man pages.

Comment: @bey0nd well, or a link to the man page that has the -J.  I don't see it here https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh

Comment: @barlop `April 14, 2013` seems a bit outdated. Just try [openssh](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh). ;-)

Comment: @bey0nd NP. Not criticizing. The message I was getting is pretty generic and likely due to the port. I will try the updated commands later without the config file and see how we go. Regarding the DNS, it looks like it might depend on the browser configuration? [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/337791/if-i-am-using-ssh-for-a-socks-proxy-do-dns-connections-go-through-it)

Comment: I tried again with the updated code. Without the config file, I couldn't get it to work. I will play around with it more later and leave an update when I work out how to do it without the config.

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: Your local Web-Server runs on a separate host with IP 192.168.1.100
            Your intermediate server runs on IP 2.3.4.5

Your local host connects to your intermediate server via ssh and does some remote port forwarding:

```
sudo ssh -R 10080:192.168.1.100:80 -R 10443:192.168.1.100:443 user@2.3.4.5
```

Your remote host connects to your intermediate server via ssh and does some local port forwarding:

```
sudo ssh -L 80:localhost:10080 -L 443:localhost:10443 user@2.3.4.5
```

In writing:
The local machine uses a ssh-tunnel with remote port forwarding to 'capture' the ports 10080 and 10443 on the `lo` interface of the intermediate server. Both remote ports are then forwarded onto port 80 and 443 of the WebServer (192.168.1.100) in your local network.
The remote machine uses its own ssh tunnel to 'capture' the ports 80 and 443 of its own `lo` interface and forwards those to port 10080 and 10443 on the `lo` interface of your intermediate server.
Therefore any application on your remote machine connecting to the internal ports localhost:80 or localhost:443 will be forwarded to the internal ports :10080 or :10443 of your intermediate server and then through your local machine on to ports 192.168.1.100:80 or 192.168.1.100:443 on the lan interface of your web server.

Hope that helps.

edit: reworked the ip addresses of the `lo` interfaces.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with dynamic port forwarding? That is why I was trying to do it with SOCKS.